# Is this slogan grammatically correct in its double use of the to-infinitive?

Tags: grammaticality, gerund-vs-infinitive

The motto of the institution where I work is:

> To explore the potential of nature to improve the quality of life

Is this (double use of the to-infinitive) grammatically correct? And if so, is it common to set up a sentence like this?

Comment: It's syntactically valid.  A little ambiguous as a slogan, as one isn't sure whether it's two independent phrases or the second one is modifying the first.

Comment: @HotLicks - The ambiguity of the motto can well be intended.

Comment: A more interesting question is whether that motto is really a sentence.

Comment: Slogans have to be catchy more than meet proper English standards, and this one is as hollow as the next that promises to improve world peace, whose potential I support.

Comment: It's not a "sentence", but slogans/mottos don't need to be.

Comment: While not wrong, it would flow more naturally if it were the following: ***Exploring*** *the potential of nature **in order** to improve the quality of life.*

Comment: That's an opinion that not everyone would share.

Comment: Absolutely no utterance at all needs to be a sentence. And what's a sentence is not defined to begin with. Ask five people, get six different answers. In the end it's just a label. You can call this utterance a sentence, or an incomplete sentence, or an excavator with floppy ears. It does not care one bit what you call it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - I think its ears are quite rigid!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to interpret this.

*To improve the quality of life* is an infinitive clause. It could be modifying *explore*:

> [Our purpose is] to explore... to improve the quality of life.

In this interpretation, *to improve the quality of life* is the purpose for your exploration.

*To improve the quality of life* could also be modifying *potential*:

> [Our purpose is] to explore the potential [to improve the quality of life] of nature.

This may sound clunky, but I simply switched the locations of the two modifiers applied to *potential* (*to improve...* and *of nature*) in order to illustrate my point.

These two methods of understanding yield very similar results, and the slogan is probably intentionally ambiguous. For more meaningless slogans and a few good laughs, read [this Cracked.com article](https://www.cracked.com/article_14983_the-9-most-meaningless-corporate-slogans.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not a prepositional phrase. It's an infinitive clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler Can't it be both? *To* is a preposition, after all...

Comment: Yes, but _improve the quality of life_ is a verb phrase, not a noun phrase, and a preposition phrase requires a preposition and a noun phrase object.

Comment: There are two _to_'s. I went to London (preposition, as usual followed by a noun phrase) / I went to turn the machine off (infinitive-marker particle, as  usual followed by an infinitive; some boldly insert an adverb).

Comment: @JohnLawler I did not know this. I will edit. If you downvoted, please consider removing your vote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Where's the train?

Comment: @Hot Licks Two _to_'s, not choo-choos.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -- To a small child it's often "to-to".

Comment: @HotLicks That was a trainwreck.